# Powerpoint - Stacked bar chart with wrong bar length

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, charts

I'm using PowerPoint 2016 on Windows 7 to create a stacked bar chart of a Yes-no-question and I'm experiencing a very odd behaviour. When the left part of the bar graph (Yes) is set to 83% or less, everything looks normal. But as soon as it is set to 84% or higher, the proportions of the chart become wrong with PowerPoint assigning too much space to the No-part.

Following are two pictures showing the difference:

[image: Wrong length with >=84]
[image: Everything ok with <=83%]
[Here you can download the minimal example that I'm using in the screenshot.](http://www.filedropper.com/buggypercentages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the axis on your chart has automatically changed the max and min values of the axis in an attempt to be helpful. If this was a line chart it might make sense for the axis to auto-adjust but on a stacked bar it's just irritating!

See here in my screengrab - the minimum axis value has jumped to 75% instead of 0%.

To fix it, click the axis and in the options box on the right, fix the minimum value to 0 and the maximum value to to 1.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, worked perfectly. Didn't notice it since I had all axes turned off for those charts.

Comment: Yeah figured that's why you missed it. Have done the same thing in the past!